# How to read the image in the a folder

Tags: python, opencv

Saying my `.py` file is in the folder named `Source`. I have another folder inside `Source` named `TestImage`. `TestImage` folder contains a file called `1.png`

`Source` folder is opened in VS Code, and I am using `cv2.imread()` to read images. I know if I move `1.png` into folder `Source`, I can do `cv2.imread("1.png")`. However, what should I do if I want to access `1.png` in folder `TestImage` ?

Comment: You could use absolute paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following directory structure...

```
.
└── Source
    ├── TestImage
    │   └── 1.png
    └── main.py
```

...and you're starting the script with `python main.py`.

You should be able to use:

```py
cv2.imread("./TestImage/1.png")
```

If you are on Windows, then you may want to use `\` instead of `/`.

Comment: Surely the `./` is unnecessary on Windows as it would be on Unix?

Comment: I would imagine that "TestImage\1.png" would be equivalent to ".\TestImage\1.png" on Windows. I prefer including it, but it is just personal preference

Answer (score 0):

According to VS Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd), the default working directory for defaults to `${workspaceFolder}` (`Source` in your case) so that

```
cv2.imread("TestImage /1.png")
```

should work.